# Get PHP variable to display after form already loaded

Tags: php

I have a PHP file for a user profile where they are able to upload a profile photo. The form is processed in a separate file that does checks in PHP on the uploaded file I currently header the user to an error page telling them the error but I want to pass the variable containing the error back to the user profile and display it.

So far I have got to this point 
FILE 1 - USER PROFILE

```
   $avatar_form .= '<form id="avatar_form" action="photo_system.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    $avatar_form .= '<h1>Change avatar</h1>';
    $avatar_form .= '<input type="file" name="avatar" required>';
    $avatar_form .= '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>';
    $avatar_form .= '<p>'.$photoerror.'</p>';
    $avatar_form .= '</form>';
```

FILE 2 - IMAGE PROCESSING FILE

```
if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
        $photoerror = "That image has no dimensions";
                echo $photoerror;
        exit(); 
    }
    $db_file_name = rand(100000000000,999999999999).".".$fileExt;
    if($fileSize > 1048576) {
        $photoerror = "Your image file was larger than 1mb";
        exit(); 
    } else if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
        $photoerror = "Please only JPG, GIF or PNG images";
        exit();
    } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
        $photoerror = "An unknown error occurred";
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to post the form to your second page, and then in the success function you can load the processed image in the container you want without refreshing the page.

If it is an error, then in the success or error function in your jQuery request, you can display some javascript alert("Error"); or you can display it in html without having to redirect them to a different page.

```
    $("#form").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "process.php", success: function(result){
            //Print the error message here
            $("#errorMessage").html(result);
        }});
    });
```

In your PHP process file, echo that **$photoerror,** and this jQuery function will pick it up and then you can display it.

Visit this link for an example: http://brian.staruk.me/php/2013/sample-jquery-php-ajax-script/